# MvvmCross clear back stack and change TabBarController select tab

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a `MvxTabBarViewController` instance `mainView`, and `mainView` has four tabs, each tab has a `UINavigationController`. Now I'm in the position like this:

```
Tab1 -> UINavigationController -> HomeView -> FirstView -> SecondView -> ...
```

I'm in the SecondView and I want to clear the back stack in Tab1, then change TabBarViewController's `selectedViewController`.

My Code:

```
if (clearHint.Body.Data["NavigationMode"] == "IncomeView")
{
    mainView.SelectedViewController = mainView.ViewControllers[2];
    return;
}
else if (clearHint.Body.Data["NavigationMode"] == "ClearStack")
{
    var navController = mainView.ViewControllers[0] as UINavigationController;
    foreach (var item in navController.ViewControllers)
    {
         if (item is HomeView)
         {
             navController.PopToViewController(item, false);
             return;
         }
     }
}
```

and

```
var clearStack = new ClearHistoryPresentationHint(new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string,string>{{ "NavigationMode", "ClearStack" }}));
ChangePresentation(clearStack);

await Task.Delay(50);

var bundle = new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "NavigationMode", "IncomeView" } });
var toInCome = new ClearHistoryPresentationHint(bundle);
ChangePresentation(toInCome);
```

If I remove this line **await Task.Delay(50);**. App will crash or not work depend on the *if/else if* order. The problem is I can not put the *clear back stack code* and *change tabbar `selectedViewController` code* all together.

So, what is the correct way to achieve this?

**Update 1**

No problem use below code without **await Task.Delay(50)**.

If I change the order *1,2* to *2,1*, app crash.

```
if (clearHint.Body.Data["NavigationMode"] == "IncomeView")
{
    // 1. Change Tab
    mainView.SelectedViewController = mainView.ViewControllers[2];

    // 2. Clear BackStack
    var navController = mainView.ViewControllers[0] as UINavigationController;

    foreach (var item in navController.ViewControllers)
    {
        if (item is HomeView)
        {
            navController.PopToViewController(item, false);
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
 }
```